# Is it possible to know the command executed by a Visual Studio Code task?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

I am programming in Java using VS Code, using the Extension Pack for Java. I can start building my project with the "Rebuild All" button, or create a .jar file with the "Export Jar..." button.

This launches a task in a one-time use "task terminal" which I can't access :

```
 *  Executing task: java (buildArtifact): default
```

The generation of the .jar files works great, but I'd like to know which command was used so I can automate it with a bash script.

I tried looking inside VS Code task configuration "tasks.json" but didn't find much.

Comment: are you asking specifically about that task with that extension? asking about all tasks is pretty broad... I'm thinking way too broad for a single question on SO. the best answer to that question would be: "read the source code". even asking for this specific task, you're not providing enough info to give a definite answer. what build system are you using? Gradle? Maven? https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 0):

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

should do the trick. The input files are space seperated.

Comment: I indeed tried this and including libraries as well but the .jar file didn't find the libraries.

Comment: If you have dependent libraries then you can't do it like that. I would rather use a generic build system such as Maven, which will allow you to make a 'fat jar' with Maven Shade. I don't recommend doing it 'manually'

Comment: I would like to do it manually to learn it, and I think the subject of my question can be interesting for other uses too.

Comment: You can look at how maven or gradle is made and learn it like that but really doing it manually when you have dependent libraries really isnt a great idea

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the **OUTPUT** panel and select `Language Support for Java` to see the log of the execution of the Java extension after you clicked on `Export Jar...`, there may be information in there about the command you are looking for.

[image]

You can also just learn how to generate jar files manually, [here's a related document](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/how-to-compile-package-and-run-a-java-program-using-command-line-tools-javac-jar-and-java) you can read(***Heading 3***). You can also search for more information yourself.

Comment: That's interesting thanks but can you not post that output as text?